# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix that is not a scalar multiple of the identity matrix. Consider the linear mapping $L$ on the vector space of real 2 × 2 matrices defined by $$L(X)=AX-XA$$

then what is the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $L$.

**My Approach**

I have proved that $A$ is diagonalizable. After that how should I proceed in order to get eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=SDS^{-1}$ with a diagonal matrix $D.$ Then $AX-XA=\lambda X$ is equivalent to
$$
S^{-1}AS\,S^{-1}XS \;-\;S^{-1}XS\,S^{-1}AS = \lambda S^{-1}XS
$$
We substitute $X=SYS^{-1}$ and we get
$$
DY-YD = \lambda Y
$$
It is easy to see that $d_i-d_j$ is an eigenvalue of $DY-YD$ with eigenvector $e_ie_j^T$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th element of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d_i$ is the $i$-th diagonal element of $D.$

As the $e_ie_j^T$ are linearly independent, we have found a complete eigenvector basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$.

The only thing left to do is to get the eigenvectors of $AX-XA$ from the eigenvectors of $DY-YD$ by unrolling the substitution.

Comment: How to find the eigenvectors?

Comment: Use the substitution from the beginning: If $Y$ is an eigenvector of $DY-YD$, then $X=SYS^{-1}$ is an eigenvector of $AX-XA.$

Comment: Zero is also the eigenvalue of DY-YD, isn’t it?

Comment: Sure, $d_i-d_j=0$ if $i=j.$